# Lua remove crates

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make a simple game but i have ome problems.
I have a game and there is a layer of 6 boxes, 5 sec later there is another layer of 6 boxes and so on..
My problem is that i want to remove 2 random boxes from each layer. in the first layer there will be some kind of object that can jump on the boxes so i want to remove 2 boxes in the first layer and put an object there lik an animal. this is the code that i have (it's only for the first layer of boxes but when i know how to do the first layer it will also work on the second layer)

```
    local physics = require("physics")
    physics.start()

    display.setDrawMode("hybrid")

    local sky = display.newImage("bkg_clouds.png")
    sky.x = display.contentWidth/2
    sky.y = display.contentHeight/2-60

    local ground = display.newImage("ground.png")
    ground.x = display.contentWidth/2
    ground.y = sky.y + display.contentHeight/2 + 80
    ground.rotation = 0.7
    local image_outline = graphics.newOutline( 2, "ground.png" )
    physics.addBody( ground , "static", {friction = 0.5, bounce = 0.2, outline = image_outline})

    local leftwall = display.newRect(0,0,1,display.contentHeight*2+100)
    local rightwall =           display.newRect(display.contentWidth,0,1,display.contentHeight*2+100)
    physics.addBody(leftwall, "static",{bounce=0.1})
    physics.addBody(rightwall, "static", {bounce = 0.1})

     for i = 27, display.contentWidth-20, display.contentWidth/6 do

        local crate = display.newImage("crate.png")
        crate.x = i
        crate.width = display.contentWidth/6.5
        crate.y = 50
        crate.height = display.contentWidth/6.5
        physics.addBody(crate, {density = 3.0, friction  = 0.5, bounce = 0.1})
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a really basic solution, but the first thing that comes to mind is generating 2 random indeces you want to use to replace the crates.
So when your loop counter matches the index, then you draw an animal instad of a create.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
local physics = require("physics")
local math = require("math") -- not sure if you need to require it.
physics.start()

display.setDrawMode("hybrid")

local sky = display.newImage("bkg_clouds.png")
sky.x = display.contentWidth/2
sky.y = display.contentHeight/2-60

local ground = display.newImage("ground.png")
ground.x = display.contentWidth/2
ground.y = sky.y + display.contentHeight/2 + 80
ground.rotation = 0.7
local image_outline = graphics.newOutline( 2, "ground.png" )
physics.addBody( ground , "static", {friction = 0.5, bounce = 0.2, outline = image_outline})

local leftwall = display.newRect(0,0,1,display.contentHeight*2+100)
local rightwall =           display.newRect(display.contentWidth,0,1,display.contentHeight*2+100)
physics.addBody(leftwall, "static",{bounce=0.1})
physics.addBody(rightwall, "static", {bounce = 0.1})

-- Generates 2 random indeces, falling in the loop boundary
local index_1 = math.random(27, display.contentWidth-20)
local index_2 = math.random(27, display.contentWidth-20)

 for i = 27, display.contentWidth-20, display.contentWidth/6 do
    -- Draw animal for matching index, otherwise a crate.
    if (i == index_1 or i == index_w) then
        -- draw animal
    else
        local crate = display.newImage("crate.png")
        crate.x = i
        crate.width = display.contentWidth/6.5
        crate.y = 50
        crate.height = display.contentWidth/6.5
        physics.addBody(crate, {density = 3.0, friction  = 0.5, bounce = 0.1})
   end
 end
```

As I said, really basic implementation, but should get the trick working for your layer.

Open issues for the implementation:

- You might have a layer without animals, as your index might not fall in your generated steps.
- Your indeces might overlap, resulting in one animal
- Your index might be at the start or end only, altering/beaking your game.

But I'll leave it up to you to deal with those checks.